# Magento2 : How can use ajax in custom module html file

Tags: magento2, checkout, ajax

I have added a template file `.html` on checkout page in order summary below `Totals`, In this file I want to add ajax to call my custom module controller and load some content on page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think it's more clear now. I will post my answer tonight.

Comment: pls post your answer. I also want the same